# DataTable Transfer to View

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to do a raw SQL statement that I transfer to a View. Do I need to have a model to hold all the information or can I just pass the DataTable? Here is my code. I just need help getting the data to the view to see it.

```
namespace DataBaseTest.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        DataTable dtFindResults = new DataTable();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            //// define a list of CustomerModel objects
            DataSet tempDS = new DataSet();

            string xSQL = "SELECT PropertyAddress FROM KDOR_vwPropertyGeneral ORDER BY PropertyAddress";
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter DbCmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter();

            //// populate a list of CustomerModel objects from database
            string MyConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["WLConnection"].ConnectionString;
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection cnn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
            System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand cmd = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand(xSQL, cnn);
            cmd.CommandTimeout = 30000;
            DbCmd.SelectCommand = cmd;

            DbCmd.Fill(tempDS,"ResultSet");
            dtFindResults = tempDS.Tables["ResultSet"];
            var x = dtFindResults.Rows.Count;
            cnn.Close();

            //// return the list of CustomerModel objects to our View
            return View(dtFindResults);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a ViewModel.

```
public class CustomerModel
{
    public string PropertyAddress { get; set; }
}

var vm = new List<CustomerModel>();
foreach (var item in dtFindResults)
{
    vm.Add(new CustomerModel { PropertyAddress = /* value from DataSet */ });
}

return View(vm);
```

Finally, your DataSet should come from a separate concern like a Repository. This repository should return a list of ViewModels you can send to the View.

Comment: So do you need multiple lists or will one list populate the model ?

Comment: From what I can see in your code, one list should suffice. Try `@model IEnumerable<CustomerModel>`